# Integrating Keycloak with Azure B2C as identity provider and using authorization code flow

Tags: angular, keycloak, azure-ad-b2c, single-page-application, oidc-client

I am trying to integrate Keycloak with Azure B2C using authorization code flow. I have Keycloak instance deployed as Azure App Service, Azure B2C tenant and demo SPA app am trying to authenticate with Azure B2C through Keycloak. First i started with trying to directly authenticate SPA with Azure B2C and after direct authentication worked i tried to put Keylcoak in the middle. And here is where i got stuck.

In azure b2c i have keycloak registered as application with redirect url specified as SPA to authenticate using authorization code flow: [image: Keycloak app registration]
In keycloak i registered Azure B2C as identity provider: [image]

[image]

[image]

And finally my SPA config looks like this (i use oidc-client):

```
authority: environment.keycloakB2CConfig.url + '/realms/' + environment.keycloakB2CConfig.realm,
client_id: environment.keycloakB2CConfig.clientId,
redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/auth-callback',
post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200',
response_type: 'code',
scope: 'https://myorgname.onmicrosoft.com/all/allApi openid profile offline_access', 
filterProtocolClaims: true,
loadUserInfo: false
```

After all those manipulations i get error in Azure B2C : Public clients should not send a client_secret when redeeming a publicly acquired grant.

It looks for me that Azure B2C treats Keycloak as public client because it is registered as SPA and because of that it is not happy with it sending client secret to authenticate. On the other hand i don't get how can i register Keycloak with Azure B2C to support authorization code flow other than SPA. I also can't find any option in Keycloak to register Identity provider without sending client secret. Documentation and tutorials are very limited so if anyone was able to successfully integrate those two in any way possible (even if it only through implicit flow) - please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right tracks and the flow will work like this:

A). The client (SPA) runs a code flow as a public client against the authorization server (AS) which is Keycloak in your case

B). The AS runs a second code flow as a cobfidential client to the identity provider (IDP) which is Azure B2C in your case

Registration will work like this:

1). Register an SPA public client in the AS, without a client secret

2). Register the AS as a confidential client in the IDP. This will generate a client ID and secret.

3). Register an [OpenID Connect IDP in the AS](https://medium.com/@ayoubchamchi/keycloak-and-idp-configuration-a4afff4bb12d) using the same client ID and secret.

So it feels like the main changes you need to make are in steps 2 and 3 above. In step 2 choose the web platform for the client in Azure B2C, not the SPA type.

Comment: I am marking this question as answered as moving to web platform fixed error i initially posted and it looks like azure b2c were able to process requests from keycloak successfully. I still don't have it working though as i have 502 bad gateway error now, but it looks like this is whole another issue